# i am getting class cast exception in bean factory in the main file while compiling

Tags: spring

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException :
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory cannot be cast to
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory     at
>   com.ashish.Test.main(Test.java:11)

How can I do to resolve this exception? Even after casting I am getting the same exception.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: can you please share code and stack of your issue

Comment: package com.ashish;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;  
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;  
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;  
public class Test {  
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    Resource resource=new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");  
    BeanFactory factory=new XmlBeanFactory(resource);  
  Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");  
    student.displayInfo();  
}  
}

Comment: package com.ashish;

public class Student {

 private String name;

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }
 public void displayInfo(){
  System.out.println("Hello"+name);
  
 }
 }

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans  
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">  
  
<bean id="studentbean" class="com.ashish.Student">  
<property name="name" value="Ashish Sharma"></property>  
</bean>  
  
</beans>

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following

```
XmlBeanFactory beanFactory = new XmlBeanFactory(new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml"));
```

But, it is recommended to use `ApplicationContext` as it provides more benefits than just a beanfactory.

```
context =  new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
Student student=(Student)factory.getBean("studentbean");
```